# Partial Specialization using a qualified name

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to partially specialize a template for a metafunction and ran into a problem.

I specialized the template like this:

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo;

template <typename A, typename B1>
struct Foo<A, typename A::template Bar<B1>> {
    /* use both A and B1*/
};

template <typename A, typename B1>
struct Foo<A, typename A::template Xyz<B1>> {
    /* use both A and B1*/
};
```

However this results (Visual Studio 2019) in

```
Error C2764: 'B1': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'Foo<A,A::Bar<B1>>' (5, 47)
```

I assume this is because I used the template parameter `A` as a qualifier in the specialication (`typename A::template Bar<B1>`).

**Is there any way to circumvent this and use parameters in template specializations as qualifiers?**

Note: In my usecase the first parameter is never really specialized. 
Theoretically it could work to nest the specialized template in another template class (i.e. currying the metafunction), but templates can only be specialized at namespace scope.

Comment: How could the compiler deduce `B1`?

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JuCNezc0oyOYKqhi

Answer (score 3):

Using a template template parameter may work out:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo;

template <typename TA, template<class> class TBar,  typename B1>
struct Foo<TA, TBar<B1>> {};
```

Given

```
struct A
{
    template<class T>
    struct Bar {};
};
```

you can form

```
Foo<A, A::Bar<int>> x;
```

and it will deduce `A`, `A::Bar` and `int` in the specialization for you. But note that no attempt is made to check that the `A` in `A::Bar` matches the  `A` given as first template parameter; it's unclear what you'd expect to happen for, say, a `Foo<double, A::Bar<int>>`.

https://godbolt.org/z/hGhsZm

Comment: Thanks for your input. I actually need both A and B1 in the specialization. I also don't know which member the specialiciations need when instanciating Foo. I updated the question with some more detail.

Comment: @LukeG Please explain what you mean with "the first parameter is never really specialized". If it's always the same, why is it a template parameter? And if it can be different, I really don't get what that statement is about...

Comment: I'm trying to say that in the specialications of the template `A` will always be specialized as `A`. Wenn instanciating the template it can obviously have different values (instanciation != specialication).

Comment: @LukeG So add back `A` as first template parameter and you're good to go... Let me edit.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume this is because I used the template parameter A as a qualifier in the specialication (typename A::template Bar).

I don't think so.

Suppose `A` is as follows

```
struct A
 { 
   template <typename B>
   using Bar = int; 
 };
```

and that you define a `Foo<A,A::Bar<B1>>`.

But `A::Bar<B1>` is `int` !

So you're defining `Foo<A, int>`.

How can, the compiler, deduce `B1` from `int` ?

It seems to me that it can't.

Possible solution (depending from your needs): if you need to specialize through `B1`, but you need `A::Bar<B1>` inside `Foo`, you can use `B1` itself as second parameter and `A::Bar<B1>` as using type inside `Foo`

```
template <typename A, typename B1>
struct Foo<A, B1> {
   using bType = A::template Bar<B1>;
};
```